# What is the best way to display notifications with time? ".setWhen ()" or "AlarmManager"?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, bootcompleted

What is the best way to display notifications with time? ".setWhen()" or "AlarmManager"?

I'm trying to create a function called "create alarm", this method creates a notification and sample 24 hours later.

When you restart your device, notifications and alarms are cleaned, thus creating the alarm keep their properties (start date, id, text, desc) on SharedPreferences for after restarting the device:

```
<receiver android:name="org.test.MyRebootReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action> android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
</ intent-filter>
</ receiver>
```

reschedule alarms.
I have not seen examples of this case (sharedpreferences + notifications + 24h).

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to display notifications with time? ".setWhen()" or "AlarmManager"?

Those have little to do with one another.

To quote [the documentation for `setWhen()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setWhen%28long%29):

> Add a timestamp pertaining to the notification (usually the time the event occurred). It will be shown in the notification content view by default

`setWhen()` is for *displaying* a time associated with a `Notification`.

The rest of your question involves *triggering* a `Notification` at a certain time. That would require the use of `AlarmManager`.